# How to create multiple instance of `directive` with different data in it

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the data in the `$scope`, according to the scope `classNames` count, i require to create elements in the page with different data from the `scope`. how to it?

I am trying to add more no.of `directive` element, But i see only one output. and i am not able to pass the `$scope` data to it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Here is my try:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="helloWorld" ng-controller="hello">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hello-world/> //added multiple times
        <hello-world/>
        <hello-world/>
        <hello-world/>
        <hello-world/>
    </div>

</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('hello', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'name1', className:'green'},
        {name:'name2', className:'blue'},
        {name:'name3', className:'brown'},
        {name:'name4', className:'yellow'},
        {name:'name5', className:'red'}
    ];
});

app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<h3 class="{item.className}">Hello World!! from color of {{item.className}}</h3>',
            scope: {
              className: '@'
            },
            link : function ($scope, elem, attr) {
            }
        }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/1/)

any one can help me to understand the concept and create the multiple instance of directive here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't close directives properly. Tag directive cannot be self-closable by definition. So what happens when you write `<hello-world />` is that the tag remains unclosed and subsequent directives are failed to be parsed.

It should be:

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<hello-world></hello-world>
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/2/

Comment: Ok, How to map the color names accordingly

Comment: Do you want to iterate `hello-world` multiple times in loop and bind color to each of them?

Comment: Yes, exactly. as well i would like to add different values of each. each need to added a click event.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it?. I got the result.

Comment: How to add click event on each and console to it's class name? ex: $(this).on('click', function(){console.log(this.className)})'

Comment: Just add ngClick directive to template of directive itself: http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/4/

Comment: I tried to convert the `directive` to standalone, But not working. how to make a `directive` became standalone and integrated in to a app? here is my try : http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/7/

Answer (score 4):

> ..I am trying to add more no.of directive element, But i see only one
>   output.

First of all, you need to close the directive tag properly. Use 
So `<hello-world><hello-world/>` instead of `<hello-world/>`. Also, place the directive in ng-repeat to get multiple elements.

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{item.name}}
            <hello-world class-name="{{item.className}}"></hello-world>
        </li>
```

> and i am not able to pass the $scope data to it.

This is because you have created an 'isolated scope' for your directive!

```
  scope: {
         className: '@'
         }
```

The `@` sign signifies that the `className` in the isolated scope will get its value from the attribute `class-name` in the directive

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<h3>Hello World!! from color of "{{className}}"</h3>',
        scope: {
            className: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {}
    }
})
```

Here's the [dmeo](http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/5/)

Comment: Generally how to fetch data from url in the angular. in case each of the `controller` may require different url and data if so how the fetch process added on each of controller. or need we make a service to provide the data according to the controllers `parameters` - can you show a way to do this? - I am very new sorry for the additional question

Comment: Not clear on the requirement. Need some code to understand better. How about posting a separate question for this ? ;)

Comment: sure, will do for you

Comment: Here is the question to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749018/angular-correct-approach-to-handle-the-data-fetch-from-server