# Angular - correct approach to handle the data fetch from server?

Tags: angularjs

Assume that, I am using the `angular-resource` - module with my `ng-app`. I don't able to understand the `data` handling easy and scale able way.. any one give me / show me a correct way to answering all this questions?

a) Generally how to fetch data from url in the angular.?

b) in case each of the controller may require different url and data if so how the `fetch` process added on each of controller.?

c) or need we make a service to provide the data according to the controllers parameters - if so how to pass parametes to service?

d) All above  have `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE`, 'POST` then how to handle all them - is all this need separate services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular-resource` as you said within a service/factory. It already provides a lot of your requirements:

```
myApp.factory("dataService", [
    "$resource",
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://someBaseUrl/:action/:id", {
            id: "@id" // default parameters
        },
        {
            // custom methods
            update: { method: "PUT" },
            doOtherStuff: { method: "GET", action: "DoOtherStuff" }
        });
    }
]);
```

The `$resource` default provides for the following REST compliant functions:

```
{ 
  'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} 
};
```

Any other functions you have to include yourself, like the `update` and the `doOtherStuff` in the example above.

The `:action` part is an easy way to provide any custom action, that is not REST compliant.

Usage in controllers:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", [
    "dataService",
    function (dataService) {
        // first parameter can be used for any extra query parameters
        // second parameter always is a callback
        var myData = dataService.query({}, function() {
            // success
        });

        var mySingleInstance = dataService.get({ id: 12 });

        this.doUpdate = function (entity) {
            dataService.update(entity);
            // Or, if the 'entity' is a resource entity:
            // entity.$update();
        }

        this.customMethod = function () {
            dataService.doOtherStuff();
        }
    }
]);
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource for the full documentation

Comment: looks good. by the way how to create standalone `directives` i tried here which not works : http://jsfiddle.net/ydkezd15/7/

Comment: But it dependents the `app` variable right? I am looking that the `directive` how can be converted as like `component'?

Comment: in the resource management, you didn't talk about the `promise` how to implement the promise here?

Comment: You do have promises, but the `$resource` call will evaluate to an object, with a `$promise` object on it. So you can do (if you want, but don't see why) do `dataService.get({ id: 12 }).$promise.then( // stuff);`